# Render image in shiny

Tags: r, shiny

I dont know why this simple code isnt working.

I've a file named app.R and a folder named www with a image named "cat.jpeg" inside.

I tried to use this:

```
ui <- fluidPage(
    h6("My cat:"),
    tags$img(src = "cat.jpeg")
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

In the output, my image just doest not appear!

If I change the "cat.jpeg" for a url link it works normally.

Comment: We can't replicate your error and it seems like every step you do is correct. My guess is that there is something wrong with that file, so it doesn't work locally.

Comment: Here's my setup: https://imgur.com/a/bXYnj4d

Comment: What error message are you getting in R or the browser console?

Comment: there's no message, just image doesnt appear. https://imgur.com/a/jLMtqVK